# Listening on socket, need to connect to another socket and communicate

Tags: php, sockets

I have a PHP script which creates and listens on a port for connections from multiple clients.

I need this socket server to also act as a client, and connect to another server. (multiple other servers).

All connections need to be able to receive/send data without "locking" up any of the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, this [library](http://code.google.com/p/phpsocketdaemon/downloads/list) or [tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1086#Heading6) can help you.

Comment: That library should do perfectly. Thanks